# Using Python, what is the best way to replace 7x with just 7 in text strings?

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am relatively new to Python and very new to nltk and regex. I have searched for guidance but not figuring it out. I am simply trying to remove any x or X that falls after an integer (should always be an integer) in text to ultimately get just the number. I have code that does what I need it to do once the X or x is removed so now I am trying to add to the code to remove that x or X from the numbers but NOT the normal text (words like exited and matrix below).

For example, if I have a text string of: 'It was a beautiful day and 710x birds exited their habitats and flew overhead. 130X of them dove down and landed on the grass while 21X of them were shot by 7 hunters. 9x birds vanished into the matrix. The remaining 550x birds kept flying away.'

I would like this:

'It was a beautiful day and 710 birds exited their habitats and flew overhead. 130 of them dove down and landed on the grass while 21 of them were shot by 7 hunters. 9 birds vanished into the matrix. The remaining 550 birds kept flying away.'

So I dont know if this is best handled by regex (Regular Expression) or nltk (Natural Language Toolkit) or simply some if statement somehow. I tokenize all the text which can be upwards of 20,000 to 30,000 tokens/words from the pdf files I extract the text from, but I would be happy to remove those x's while still a huge string or after they have been made into tokens. No matter to me. Thank you very much for any assistance ...

Comment: Definitely regex over nltk (no need to nuke a fly). Look up `re.sub`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This matches x with a look behind assertion that the prior character is a digit and replaces the x with nothing.

```
re.sub('(?<=\d)[xX]', '', s)
```

Comment: Very elegant; Too bad it clobbers `4x4` which was probably not asked for by the OP 

Comment: @DimaTisnek that could be fixed by using `(?<=\d)[xX](?!\d)` to not remove an x between two digits.

Comment: Thank you everyone - all these answers are very helpful. I know I am not supposed to simply write thanks, but I cannot upvote yet .. so thank you all. Now I need to get smart on all this regex syntax...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import re

text = 'It was a beautiful day and 710x birds exited their habitats and flew overhead. 130X of them dove down and landed on the grass while 21X of them were shot by 7 hunters. 9x birds vanished into the matrix. The remaining 550x birds kept flying away.'

re.sub(r'(\d+)[xX]', r'\1', text)

# >>> 'It was a beautiful day and 710 birds exited their habitats and flew overhead. 130 of them dove down and landed on the grass while 21 of them were shot by 7 hunters. 9 birds vanished into the matrix. The remaining 550 birds kept flying away.'
```

---

## What's this?

`re.sub` is substitution by regular expression. First parameter is regex to find, and second is regex to replace.

`r'(\d+)[xX]'` is made of

```
\d+ <= 1 or more integer sequence
[xX] <= 1 x or X
() <= keep it to use afterwards
```

`r'\1'` means first kept strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
def parseNumeric(data):
  for each in data:
    noX =''
    for i in each:
      if i.isdigit():
        noX+=i
    if noX != '':
      data[data.index(each)]=noX
  return " ".join(str(x) for x in data)



theData = "It was a beautiful day and 710x birds exited their habitats and flew overhead. 130X of them dove down and landed on the grass while 21X of them were shot by 7 hunters. 9x birds vanished into the matrix. The remaining 550x birds kept flying away."

print("\n BEFORE \n")

print(theData)

print("\n AFTER \n")

print(parseNumeric(theData.split()))
```

Check the [DEMO](https://repl.it/repls/EmbellishedSphericalPackages), I know that not the best solution but hope it helps.